# Android UI is not updating

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm working on a countdown that shows seconds remaining to start of the game. So I put TextView into middle of layout and in for loop I am changing the text of TextView, playing the sound using MediaPlayer, then waits 1 second and repeat the proccesss.

The problem is that my text view is not updating - after finishing whole for loop it just change TextView to last text that should be displayed. But since all sounds was played, I can say that Activity is running normaly. So I'm looking for some easy way how to update my UI. I saw some examples of AsynTask, but I think that's too difficult solution for this simple problem. Also, I've tried using handle to change text, but it has got no effect.

My code:

This is in onResume() method:

```
    //Using handler to delay countdown, 
            //so Activity have enough time to display view
    hand.postDelayed((new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            countdownToStart();
            game.start();
        }

    }), 1000);
```

countdownToStart() method:

```
protected void countdownToStart(){
    int soundSource[] = {R.raw.cntdwn_three, R.raw.cntdwn_two, R.raw.cntdwn_one, R.raw.cntdwn_go};
    final String nums[] = {"3", "2", "1", "GO"};
    final TextView countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.challenge_countdown_text);
    Handler hand2 = new Handler();

    //4 different texts = 4 cycles of for loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        //Load sound
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            countdownSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), soundSource[i]);
            if(countdownSound != null)
                break;
        }
        if(countdownSound == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.sound_load_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onBackPressed();
        }
        countdownSound.start();

        //Set textview
        countdownText.setText(nums[i]);
        if(i == 3)
            countdownText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200);

        //Delay between countdowns
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);

        //Release MediaPlayer
        countdownSound.release();

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please use a CountDownTimer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Never Sleep on the UI thread - of course it doesn't update, it can't, it's sleeping!  In fact, unless you REALLY understand Sleep, don't use it at all.

Comment: @Simon I thought that i'm just calling method that waits sometime and then return. I wasn't expecting that it will put whole activity into sleep.

Comment: @A.S. this solve my problem, thanks for the idea, somehow i forget that I can use CountDownTimer. Post this as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try **RunOnUIThread** by creating a **new Thread**

**Updated**

```
final TextView countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.challenge_countdown_text);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
             //Load sound
                for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
                    countdownSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), soundSource[i]);
                        if(countdownSound != null)
                            break;
                }
                if(countdownSound == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.sound_load_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    onBackPressed();
                }
                countdownSound.start();

                //Set textview
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        countdownText.setText(nums[i]);
                        if(i == 3)
                            countdownText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
    // handle exception     
        }
      }
    }).start();

    //Delay between countdowns
    SystemClock.sleep(1000);

    //Release MediaPlayer
    countdownSound.release();

}
```

Comment: Inside countdownToStart() method

Comment: put a flag or some condition, that you want in **YOUR_CONDTION** in while loop

Comment: I messed up before, see the edit. I don't think you need handler here.

Comment: Also try removing either **Thread.sleep(1000);** or **SystemClock.sleep(1000);** also by putting **countdownSound.release();** below **Thread.sleep(1000);**

Answer (score 0):

I'm 7 years behind schedule, but..
If you're using view binding,
And already setup binding, check if in setContentView it's R.layout.whateverlayout or binding.getRoot()